# How can I export the members of a twitter list to a csv file?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to find a way to export the members of a twitter list to a CSV file.
This would be for one of my own Twitter lists.

Comment: Writing a CSV is easy enough, but you'll need to parse the info first.  Do you have a specific language in mind;  Python, Lua...

Comment: Actually - I just figured it out without having to use code - one can use Tweetdeck for this - explained here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/backup-export-twitter-lists/